# Does the filter, $F$, on $S$ exist such that $p,q\in S$ and $p,q\in \lim{F}$

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, general-topology, discrete-mathematics, filters

Consider two points $p,q\in S$ with $p\ne q$. Is it possible to find a filter, $F$, on $S$ such that all neighborhoods of $p$ and $q$ are contained in $F$?
I would assume that when $p\ne q$ then, in the general case, there exist two neighborhoods $N_p$ and $N_q$ such that $N_p\cap N_q=\emptyset$ which would mean that $F$ is not a filter. However, my lecturer said that such a filter does exist.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the interpretation of "all neighborhoods of $p$ and $q$".  If, as you interpreted it, it means all neighborhoods of $p$ are in the filter and also all neighborhoods of $q$ are in it, then as you say, in a Hausdorff space it's not possible.  On the other hand, if it means that all sets which are both a neighborhoods of $p$ and a neighborhood of $q$ simultaneously are in the filter, then in fact the collection of such sets is already a filter.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Assuming we're looking for a filter on the whole power set of $S$, I think that's not quite correct because the collection of neighborhoods is not necessarily closed upward $S$ (and in fact won't be in general).  But the collection of sets *containing* such neighborhoods works, as stated in my answer below.

Comment: I use the definition of neighborhood that it's anything that contains an open set that contains the base point.  (If I want to restrict to the case of an open set that contains the base point, I use the term "open neighborhood".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F= \{ X \mid \exists U \text{ open such that } U \subseteq X \land \{p, q \} \subseteq U  \}$ be the collection of sets that contain an open set containing both $p$ and $q$.  Then $F$ is the desired filter.

If $X, Y \in F$, let $U \subseteq X, V \subseteq Y$ with $p, q \in U, p, q \in V$.  Then $U \cap V$ is open, $p, q \in U \cap V$, and $U \cap V \subseteq X \cap Y$, so we have $X \cap Y \in F$.

It's trivial, of course, that if $X \in F$ and $X \subseteq Y$, then also $Y \in F$.

These two facts establish that $F$ is a filter.